# CircleImageView not loading image from URL using Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have recently started learning android development properly, after a while of just skimming the basics, and I am building a basic application that will allow a user to save details about themselves.

The app doesn't really serve any purpose other than as a learning project.

I am using hdodenhof's CircleImageView, found here:
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

and what i believe to be the latest version of Picasso found here:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Whenever i try to use Picasso to get an image from a URL, the CircleImageView that i am trying to apply the image to, which has a placeholder src applied to start with, just disappears, which i am assuming means it is removing the placeholder image but never applying the image from the internet.

My latest attempt:

```
public class settings extends AppCompatActivity {

private CircleImageView profile_picture;
private EditText user_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings2);

     profile_picture = findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_image);
     user_name = findViewById(R.id.settings_enter_user_name);



    Button search_player = findViewById(R.id.settings_seach_user_button);
    search_player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            String imageURL = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
            Picasso.get().load(imageURL).noFade().fit().into(profile_picture);

        }
    });
```

Any and all help is appreciated, let me know if you need me to provide any additional information.

Thanks

Edit:- Typo.

Comment: What errors and exceptions do you get?

Comment: Check debug in `Log` maybe it is `OutOfMemory` exception and because `Picasso` will handle it there will be no crash but no image as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to the people who helped!

Turns out i was just being daft and forgot to add the INTERNET permission.

Whoops.

Thanks.